# Can we use react native (npm) packages in react native expo project

Tags: javascript, android, ios, react-native, expo

I have created a react-native application using expo and now am working on it, I want to use some react native (npm: react-native-material-dropdown, react-native-datepicker, etc.,) packages in my expo project, but I am not able to use those in my expo project...

Is there any possibility or solution to make it happen?

Thanks in advance...

Comment: Did my answer resolve your problem? If yes feel free to accept it (click checkmark) if not let me know.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to use them in your Expo Project.. just run `npm install --save react-native-material-dropdown` for example and after that you should be able to use it.